# Unable to pan or move the osmdroid map

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm using the osmdroid map in a sample application. The map is seen,zoom works,and everything is fine except that i'm unable to pan/move the map.

My main xml code is:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    </org.osmdroid.views.MapView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

My java code is:

```
 public class MapTest extends Activity {

private MapView mapView;
private MapController mapController;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_test);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    mapController = this.mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(10);
    GeoPoint mapCenter = new GeoPoint(17.4467, 78.4667);
    mapController.setCenter(mapCenter);
}

}
```

Any ideas as to how to enable the movement?

Answer (score 6):

Try removing:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

from your MapView. That makes the MapView consume touch events and it messes with the dispatchTouchEvent method. You might also try removing the focusable stuff too.

Answer (score 2):

```
mapView.setClickable(false);
```

It worked for me.

You should give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Just install previous version for now, looks like there's a bug in 3.0.9.

Comment: I've also experienced this. Somebody else has raised an issue on the gCode site: https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=415&start=100

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
mapView.setClickable(false);
```