# Cannot move the map using OsmDroid 3.0.10

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

After updating to the latest library version the map isn't scrollable anymore. The only controls that work are zoom in/out.

```
this.mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
this.mMapView.setUseSafeCanvas(true);
this.registerForContextMenu(mMapView);
this.mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
this.mMapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
this.mMapView.setClickable(true);
this.mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to pan or move the osmdroid map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727055/unable-to-pan-or-move-the-osmdroid-map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to remove the line, without success:

```
 this.mMapView.setClickable(true);
```

It was also necessary removing the following line:

```
this.registerForContextMenu(mMapView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the line:

```
this.mMapView.setClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by removing the line:

```
this.mMapView.setClickable(true);
```